# i want to pickup the persons who have an end of their contract in period of 6 months

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$query ="SELECT *
         FROM expiration 
       where 'expirationdate' BETWEEN  (DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%m/%d/%Y')) AND  (DATE_FORMAT(curdate()+ INTERVAL 6 MONTH,'%m/%d/%Y'))";
```

where is the problem

Comment: remove the date format that os no date format for mysql

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Column names must be in Backticks see [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)
and as mentioned don't convert the date column

```
$query ="SELECT *
         FROM expiration 
       where `expirationdate` BETWEEN  curdate() AND  curdate() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH";
```

Comment: thank you sooooooooooooo much i have been for 1 day look for a solution finally it works <3